# I initiated a swap on blockchain, but intead of going to receive adress it created a contract without abi or functions in it

Tags: function-selector

I initiated a swap on bsc blockchain, but instead of funds going to receive adress it created a contract without abi or functions in it.
Is it possible to receive the funds back?
I own the created contract btw, because it was created out of my wallet.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: >  I own the created contract btw, because it was created out of my wallet.

No you don't, there's no such thing as a built in "ownership" in smart contracts, if you don't include a mechanism in it that allows you (as the deployer/owner) to do special things that another user can't do, you don't have any specific power over it. Apart from that, the bot is correct, we're lacking way too many details to answer your question. Please tell us what you did exactly when you "initiated a swap on bsc blockchain", and share your code

Comment: It is likely you incorrectly send a deployment transaction instead of a swap transaction.